# Member "getSingleKey" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in type(contract KeyHelper)

Tags: solidity

I could see no reason for this not to work. Here's my code:

**MintAndTransfer2.sol**

```
import "./KeyHelper.sol";

contract NFTCreator is ExpiryHelper {
    HederaTokenService public hts;

    function createNft(
        string memory name,
        string memory symbol,
        string memory memo,
        uint32 maxSupply,
        uint32 autoRenewPeriod
    ) external payable returns (address) {
        IHederaTokenService.TokenKey[]
            memory keys = new IHederaTokenService.TokenKey[](1);
        
        keys[0] = KeyHelper.getSingleKey( //the error is here
            KeyHelper.KeyType.SUPPLY,
            KeyHelper.KeyValueType.CONTRACT_ID,
            address(this)
        );
```

**KeyHelper.sol**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
pragma solidity 0.8.17;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

import "./HederaTokenService.sol";

abstract contract KeyHelper {
    using Bits for uint256;
    address supplyContract;

    mapping(KeyType => uint256) keyTypes;

    enum KeyType {
        ADMIN,
        KYC,
        FREEZE,
        WIPE,
        SUPPLY,
        FEE,
        PAUSE
    }
    enum KeyValueType {
        INHERIT_ACCOUNT_KEY,
        CONTRACT_ID,
        ED25519,
        SECP256K1,
        DELEGETABLE_CONTRACT_ID
    }

    constructor() {
        keyTypes[KeyType.ADMIN] = 1;
        keyTypes[KeyType.KYC] = 2;
        keyTypes[KeyType.FREEZE] = 4;
        keyTypes[KeyType.WIPE] = 8;
        keyTypes[KeyType.SUPPLY] = 16;
        keyTypes[KeyType.FEE] = 32;
        keyTypes[KeyType.PAUSE] = 64;
    }

    
    
[...]
  

    function getSingleKey(
        KeyType keyType,
        KeyValueType keyValueType,
        bytes memory key
    ) internal view returns (IHederaTokenService.TokenKey memory tokenKey) {
        tokenKey = IHederaTokenService.TokenKey(
            getKeyType(keyType),
            getKeyValueType(keyValueType, key)
        );
    }

    function getSingleKey(
        KeyType keyType,
        KeyValueType keyValueType,
        address key
    ) internal view returns (IHederaTokenService.TokenKey memory tokenKey) {
        tokenKey = IHederaTokenService.TokenKey(
            getKeyType(keyType),
            getKeyValueType(keyValueType, key)
        );
    }

    
}

library Bits {
    uint256 internal constant ONE = uint256(1);

    // Sets the bit at the given 'index' in 'self' to '1'.
    // Returns the modified value.
    function setBit(uint256 self, uint8 index) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return self | (ONE << index);
    }
}
```

In fact I have this problem for all my functions from another file. I even tried to put all my files in the same folder but it changed nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to extend your contract.
eg.

```
contract NFTCreator is ExpiryHelper, KeyHelper {
.....
```

Comment: Crazy. why is that. It used to work fine without extending. I have many examples of code where it works/worked without extending.

Comment: You can not use any method public or internal without extending it. But private methods can not be used in any condition.